# Docker-compose/File unable to link php symfony web service to Javascript API

Tags: javascript, docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

My college group and I are working on a software suite similar to IFTTT and/or Zapier, the suite is broken down into 3 parts, an application server that we choose to develop in JS, a mobile client in flutter, and a web client in php symfony.
To have a complete project we must deploy everything with docker (file and compose). At this moment we've managed to successfully build each components even with our docker-compose but the problem is that our application server and our webclient don't seem to communicate and we can't understand why.

PS we must respect the following:

The application server must run exposing the port 8080

The webclient service must run exposing the port 8081

Here's our code:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: "./API/"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - default

  mobile:
    build: "./MobileApp/"
    volumes:
      - apk:/Mobile/"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - './WebClient/public/:/usr/src/app'
      - './docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - default

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - ./WebClient/.env
    user: 1000:1000
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  apk:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

`Application server (API) Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node" , "index.js"]
```

`Web client (php) Dockerfile`

```
FROM composer:2.0 as composer

FROM php:7.4.1-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=1000:1000 WebClient /usr/src/app

RUN PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/app/vendor/bin:bin

RUN composer install
```

`nginx default.conf`

```
server {
    server_name ~.*;

    location / {
        root /usr/src/app;

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/public/index.php;
    }

    error_log /dev/stderr debug;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
}
```

`Mobile app Dockerfile (mobile)`

```
FROM cirrusci/flutter

COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
##USER ROOT
RUN rm -f .packages
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter clean
RUN flutter build apk

RUN mkdir /Mobile/
RUN cp build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk /Mobile/client.apk
```

`docker-compose build && docker-compose up output`

```
Creating b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_api_1    ... done
Creating b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_php_1    ... done
Creating b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_mobile_1 ... done
Creating b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_nginx_1  ... done
Attaching to b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_mobile_1, b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_api_1, b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_php_1, b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_nginx_1
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
api_1     | server is listening on 8080
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
b-yep-500-lil-5-1-area-colinmartinage_mobile_1 exited with code 0
nginx_1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?), exiting
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php_1     | [07-Mar-2021 09:50:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Comment: How do you configure the proxy from nginx to api?

Comment: We don't have any specific configuration, I think that everything we have is described in .conf for nginx (we're still learning ;) )